# crystal reports formula to display each decimal in 8 digit number in a separate field

Tags: crystal-reports

I've researched this and the formula below works fine for a varchar but my field is a decimal. When trying to substitute my field in I get an error "a string or an array of values is required here".

If I have a 8 digit number and want to display each field one at a time in a separate field how would I go about it?

```
Local StringVar Message1 :="";
if not isnull({patient_encounter.enc_nbr})
then Message1 := Message1 + {patient_encounter.enc_nbr}[1 to 8] ;
Message1[1 to 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to string and then use

```
Local StringVar Message1 :="";
if not isnull(ToText({patient_encounter.enc_nbr}))
then Message1 := Message1 + ToText({patient_encounter.enc_nbr})[1 to 8] ;
Message1[1 to 1]
```

Comment: Nice! I have been using Crystal a long time and had no idea you could output a portion of a string using [# to #].. much easier than mid

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried using the ToText as well and get an error of "a field required here" even though I'm pulling that field from the db directly, not typing it in to avoid any mistypes.